# Translation of "Kfz Sachverständiger"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I'm struggeling with the correct English terms for "Kfz Sachverständiger" and "Kfz Sachgutachter".

Should I translate "Kfz" into "fcc" directly or is this used otherwise here?

So, the result would be "ffc appraiser", is this correct?

Comment: For those who also wonder: "kfz" can mean kubisch-flächenzentriert (a certain way atoms are arranged in a crystal), so its translation would be "fcc", face-centered cubic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kfz is an abbreviation of ***K***raft**f**ahr**z**eug and means *any vehicle that has a motor*. In most cases, that means: a car, a motorbike, a lorry.

A *Sachverständiger* is a person who has *Sachverstand* (expertise). There are some job titles made from that, for example the *Kfz-Sachverständiger*. That's an "approved car expert". It may be an appraiser but it may also be an engineer working at the local vehicle inspection centre.

Comment: Note there is even a specific law for this profession (the *Kraftfahrsachverständigengesetz*): https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amtlich_anerkannter_Sachverständiger_oder_Prüfer , http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/kfsachvg/